# Creating StreamProvider in flutter app needs correction

Tags: flutter, stream

I am learning about StreamProviders and ChangeNotifierProvider and how to use them in a flutter app.

The problem I am having is when I create the StreamProvider in main.dart. I am getting this error
Instance member 'getAgencyTrxn' can't be accessed using static access. (Documentation)
as designated by a red line under getAgencyTrxn(). I have been following a tutorial and also some posts here but none of them quite match what I am doing.

How do I fix this error?

Here is what I have so far:

main.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;

    globals.newTrxn = true;

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<TrxnProvider>(create: (context) => TrxnProvider()),

        StreamProvider<TrxnProvider>(
            create: (context) => TrxnProvider.getAgencyTrxn(),
            initialData: []),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: LoginScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

trxn_provider.dart

```
class TrxnProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();

  String? _clientFName;
  String? _clientLName;

  // Getters
  String? get clientFName => _clientFName;
  String? get clientLName => _clientLName;

  // Setters
  changeclientFName(String value) {
    _clientFName = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  changeclientLName(String value) {
    _clientLName = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  loadValues(QueryDocumentSnapshot trxns) {
    _clientFName = trxns['clientFName'];
    _clientLName = trxns['clientLName'];
  }

  getAgencyTrxn() {
    return firestoreService.getAgencyTrxns();
  }

  saveTrxn() {
    if (globals.newTrxn == true) {
      _trxnId = uuId.v4();
      globals.newTrxn = false;
    }

    var newTrxn = Trxns(
        clientFName: clientFName,
        clientLName: clientLName);

    firestoreService.saveTrxn(newTrxn);
  }

  deleteTrxn(String trxnId) {
    firestoreService.deleteTrxn(trxnId);
  }
}
```

firestore_service.dart

```
class FirestoreService {
  FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

Stream<QuerySnapshot> getAgencyTrxns() async* {
    yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId)
        .collection('trxns')
        .where('trxnStatus', isNotEqualTo: 'Closed')
        .snapshots();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I needed to change this

```
create: (context) => TrxnProvider.getAgencyTrxn()
```

to this

```
create: (context) => TrxnProvider().getAgencyTrxn()
```